# What happens to a close casting window if you close a question from the flag tools tab?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, 10k-tools, flag-queue

### Steps to reproduce:

Be careful, this is very specific situation. Go to [**flagging tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=flags) and try to find a question, which is going to be closed (question, which has 4 close votes) and click the **close question (4)** button and close the question by **Vote To Close** button (without previous flagging, but maybe it's not important). That's what happened to me for a second time:

[image]

The question gets closed, but an empty notification pops up and the close casting window stucks on the never ending progress animation unless you close the window or that notification.

### Question:

Could you check this problem ?

Comment: I had this happen to me earlier today. I thought maybe it was temporary, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: No repo on <10k.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this.